# autowiring in executable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, executable-jar, autowired

my project works fine in eclipse, but when I'm trying to run it from executable jar file it fails with "nosuchbeandefinitionexception no matching bean of type found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency".
I use autowiring with context:component-scan from application context. applicationcontext.xml is available for jar file.

so I can't understand why it works in eclipse and in the same time fails from jar. any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding all the required components in the classpath of your executable when you run it from the command line?

Comment: yes, eclipse does it automatically

Comment: Please post Thema complete stacktrace, often there in a hint for whats going on.

Comment: We'll need to see some spring configuration and the stacktrace

Comment: There are many reasons it could fail, but we would need to see what I mentioned earlier and also you need to tell us how you are building the jar